# Two STM32 devices out of sync

Tags: led, stm32

I have two basic STM32G0 boards with a simple LED.
I have set up a simple program to blink that led every 500 ms.
I have both devices connected to same power and turn them on at same time.

They start to blink at the same time, but after a few minits they start to go out of sync, and keeps going more an more out of sync.
They are the same devices with same code uploaded to both.

Is there a easy fix for this?

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  uint32_t then = 0, now = 0;
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

        now = HAL_GetTick();
        if (now - then >= 1000) { // Only if the current tick is 500 ms after the last

            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0);

            then = now; // Reset then = now
        }

        // Toggle the LED
        //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0);

        // Wait for 500 ms
        //HAL_Delay(500);

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIDiv = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: That code can't be all that your MCU is running. What do you use as a clock source? Internal oscillator, external crystal, etc?

Comment: Internal oscillator

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is each board uses it's own clock source. It is impossible that they have the exact same frequency to begin with, so since they do not use the same clock source, the boards are not in sync in any way, just like two wall clocks.

The second problem is that you are using the internal oscillators.

They have only about 1% tolerance. One board might run 1% slower than 16 MHz and the other board might run 1% faster than 16 MHz so they do not stay in sync.

Internal oscillators are only good when you don't need or care about at what frequency it really runs, as long as it's running approximately at some speed.

The easy fix is to not use the internal oscillator but a better clock source like a crystal.

With using crystals, the boards still are not in sync as they do not use the same clock. But crystals have about 100ppm tolerance or better, which means 0.01% tolerance, or 100x better than internal oscillator.

Another option is to use the same clock source on both MCUs so they stay in sync no matter what. Or have a synchronization pulse or data wire between them so each board can run with their own clock but still know when to blink the LED at the same time as the other board.

Please note the wording, the internal oscillators are within 1% tolerance. It means that they are not always 1% off from the nominal but just the worst case. In practice they are ticking closer to th nominal frequency.

You can also trim the internal oscillator speed so they run closer at same frequency.

Even if you use crystals, the boards will still not run at the same speed, just more accurately closer to the nominal speed.

Crystals may achieve 100 ppm or less.

For reference, a wall clock that drifts 1 minute per year is about 2 ppm off from the nominal tick rate.

Comment: but if it was only 1% wouldnt it take ages to go out of sync, they go out of sync after a min or so

Comment: 1% means the devices are off by 1 second after only 100 seconds - less than two minutes.

Comment: @fiven80440 No. Being 1% out of sync means they are 1% out of sync immediately. Each time code waits 500ms, one MCU may wait anywhere between 495 to 505 ms. It really is that bad.

Comment: ok thankyou, i guess i will have to add a crystal

Comment: @fiven80440 Maybe. Or trim the oscillators yourself. They have a calibration register. But even with crystals, they still blink out of sync. They will just drift 100x slower.

Comment: im fine with them out of sync a little bit, i just didnt understand why it was so far out so quick

Answer (score 1):

The [STM32G0 = RCC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/product_training/STM32G0-System-Reset-and-clock-control-RCC.pdf) documentation states on page 15 that the HSI16 (16 MHz) clock has a typical accuracy of ± 1%.

You can't expect better than that unless you come up with some way of synchronising the clocks to each other or some other external reference.

From your comment to JustMe's answer:

> But if it was only 1% wouldnt it take ages to go out of sync, they go out of sync after a min or so?

A 1% error on a 500 ms blink pattern will give a 5 ms error per blink. After 50 blinks that will give a 250 ms error which means that the two blinkers will be 180° out of phase. 50 blinks will take 25 seconds at 500 ms per blink.

What you are seeing is to be expected.

Comment: it takes about 1 min to notice them being out of sync, if it was a 1% differance shouldnt it take longer?

Comment: See the update. I can't figure out from your code whether you're 500 ms refers to the complete cycle or if you have 500 ms on followed by 500 ms off (1000 ms per cycle).